# Filezilla some files transferred Failed. How to re-transfer failed files

Tags: file, file-transfer, filezilla

I'm trying to upload files to server using filezilla, most of my files are uploaded but some files failed to transfer..But I didn't see which files are failed.

It takes hours to upload all the files again..

Anyone please help me to solve this issue, How can I re-transfer the failed files.

Answer (score 5):

You can click **Reset and requeue all** and all files will be moved from the *Failed* tab to the *Queued* tab. Then you can process the queue again.

Answer (score 2):

Like Roman Snitko's response, I would say that clicking **Reset and requeue all** to move all files from the Failed tab to the Queued tab is the best way to go.  However, please make sure you export your failed files list before you select **Reset and requeue all**.

Occasionally, when I select **Reset and requeue all**, FileZilla will display a message that says "Not all items can be requeued" and then CLEARS YOUR FAILED ITEMS LIST without entering them onto the queue, leaving you with no way to recover the list (I think).

This happened to me with FileZilla 3.45.1 and I have not yet determined how to recover the failed items list if this happens and no backup has already been created.  I'm not sure if this is still a bug in later versions.

Comment: I just had this error happen in FileZilla 3.57.

Answer (score 0):

Which filezilla version do you use? Filezilla should retry/reque automatically! There's still no function to resend failed files BUT if you reupload the whole bunch of files again filezilla would ask you how to handle existing files > chose to leave existing files alone > only missing files will be uploaded

Short: reupload all files and choes to leave existing files alone. This worked fine for me.